# Ruby on Rails - Using where condition for associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a count of activities (belongs_to Students model) where the students gender (string on student) is equal to "male":

```
@boysout = Activity.where(status: "Out", 
                            user_id: current_user,
                            student: {gender: "male" }).count
```

This is the error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student.gender: SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."status" = ? AND
>   "activities"."user_id" = 1 AND "student"."gender" = ?

What is the correct syntax?

Edit: Here's the schema:

```
create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_activities_on_student_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_activities_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.integer  "grade"
    t.string   "school"
    t.string   "teacher"
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
```

Comment: Join it with table STUDENT

Comment: @beaconhill Can you please update the question with the schema of `students` and `activities`? And what is the significance of `user_id` column? Do you have another model for `users`?

Comment: @ArunKumar just added it!

Answer (score 2):

More cleaner solution can be this :).

Assuming `student has_many activities` associations:-

```
  Student.includes(:activities).where(gender:"male").where( :activities => { :status => "Out", user_id: current_user.id } ).count
```

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student.gender: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "activities"."id") FROM "activities" LEFT OUTER JOIN "students" ON "students"."id" = "activities"."student_id" WHERE "student"."gender" = ? AND "activities"."status" = ? AND "activities"."user_id" = ?`

Comment: i have updated my answer..moreover what do you get after hitting  Student.includes(:activities).where(gender:"male") ?

Comment: It's not filtering out students where gender = "male"

Comment: what you get for :  Student.includes(:activities).where(gender:"male") ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a `join`?

```
Activity.joins(:student)
        .where(status: "Out", user_id: current_user.id)
        .where(student: { gender: "male" })
        .count
```

Comment: Errored out `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student.gender: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "students" ON "students"."id" = "activities"."student_id" WHERE "activities"."status" = ? AND "activities"."user_id" = ? AND "student"."gender" = ?`